# Export styled-component's component

Tags: javascript, typescript, styled-components, storybook

Having the source code:

```
const StyledHorizontalRule = styled.hr`
  border: 1px solid;
  color: ${props => props.theme.palette.divider_inverted };
  width: auto;
`;

export const HorizontalRule = () => <StyledHorizontalRule />;
```

and how I import the component:

```
import { HorizontalRule } from '../../../ui-elements-layout/components/HorizontalRule/index';
```

I got:

```
[!] Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import 
files that are not JavaScript)
../ui-elements-layout/components/HorizontalRule/HorizontalRule.tsx 
(10:36)
8: `;
9: 
10: export const HorizontalRule = () => <StyledHorizontalRule />;
                                    ^
```

How should I export the component properly, what are best practices to do it?

EDIT: `index.ts` has:

```
export * from './HorizontalRule';
```

Comment: You can just `export default StyledHorizontalRule;` and then `import { StyledHorizontalRule } from '../../../ui-elements-layout/components/HorizontalRule/index'` and then use in the way you want: `<StyledHorizontalRule />`

Comment: Are you using fat arrow functions elsewhere? The does not seem to be related to styled-components

Comment: Maybe the issue is not strictly related to styled-components, rather to TypeScript as tags shown also.